# JavaScript doesn't work after document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document.write

I am using jQuery BlockUI for opening a new webpage that takes some time due to a lot of database querying with the following javascript:

```
function productSheet(url2) {
       $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS = {};
        $.blockUI({ });
        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            success: function (respones) {
                var win = window.open();
                with (win.document) {
                    open();
                    write(respones);
                    close();
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

At the new page i got some jQuery JavaScript and a reference to the external jQuery script. However when i render the page after the JavaScript above all my script throws error for: "$ undefined". 
I can refresh the page and everything starts working and I am not getting any script errors.

This problem only occur when I am debugging in IE 9, on Firefox everything works (no JavaScript errors and the script works).

Does anyone have any idea on whats the problem can be?

EDIT:

The page iam rendering is a MVC 3 view. So the script above goes to an MVC action that returns a this view:

```
@model WebApplication.Controllers.ProductSheetModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Sheet - @Model.ArticleMain.ArticleMain.T0018_BENAM</title>

    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../css/ProductSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    @if (Model.IsPDFExport == false)
    { 
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ArticleMain, "ProductSheetHeader")
    }
    ... some more partical views...
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabelheight1 = $("#divNutritiveValues").height();
    var tabelheight2 = $("#divMarking").height();
    if (tabelheight1 > tabelheight2) {
        $("#divMarking").css("height", tabelheight1 + "px");
        $("#divNutritiveValues").css("height", tabelheight1 + "px");
    }
    if (tabelheight2 > tabelheight1) {
        $("#divNutritiveValues").css("height", tabelheight2 + "px");
        $("#divMarking").css("height", tabelheight2 + "px");
    }

    var tableheightStore = $("#divStore").height();
    var tableheightCooking = $("#divCooking").height();
    if (tableheightCooking > tableheightStore) {
        $("#divCooking").css("height", tableheightCooking + "px");
        $("#divStore").css("height", tableheightCooking + "px");
    }
    if (tableheightStore > tableheightCooking) {
        $("#divCooking").css("height", tableheightStore + "px");
        $("#divStore").css("height", tableheightStore + "px");
    }

    var tableInfoProvid = $("#divInformationProvider").height();
    var tableManufac = $("#divManufacturer").height()
    if (tableInfoProvid > tableManufac) {
        $("#divManufacturer").css("height", tableInfoProvid + "px");
        $("#divInformationProvider").css("height", tableInfoProvid + "px");
    }
    if (tableManufac > tableInfoProvid) {
        $("#divInformationProvider").css("height", tableManufac + "px");
        $("#divManufacturer").css("height", tableManufac + "px");
    }
});
```

Comment: I see three fails here - using jQuery 1.3, using `with`, and using `document.write` ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $ is undefined on your page on IE.

Normally, jQuery sets $ as a reference to the `jQuery` object. [See docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

For some reason, either the $ reference is being removed or is not happening on IE. Can you post more of your code?

One work-around would be to use `jQuery` instead of `$`

But it would be good to better understand what is actually happening on IE.

Comment: thx for ur reply, i have change $ to jQuery but i got the same error "jQuery is undefined". i will post a new answer with some more code from the page that im rendering.

Comment: is it possible to use any other javascript syntax rather than using document.write as i do above?

Comment: I'd start with using current jQuery (1.7.2) rather than 1.3.2. You're using such an old version, it simply may not support IE 9. Instead of document.write, you can explicitly add elements to the dom, or set innerHTML to change contents. But document.write is not your main problem and may not be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused as your JavaScript registrations are not occurring with your AJAX posts, meaning that they get lost and don't get re-registered.

This is a common issue when working with AJAX, and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32392/Adding-JavaScript-and-CSS-during-an-AJAX-Partial-P) explains it perfectly and provides what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with a solution and want to share it with you. In my site i created a script checking if jquery was undefined.

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
      window.location.reload();
 }
```

after i have reloaded the page again all my scripts work, maybe not the best of solutions but it works so i am happy.